# Late status is missing in studentSubmission returned by the teacher

Tags: google-classroom

I can't find a way to determine if a student turned in an assignment after the due date if the teacher has returned the assignment to the student.

For example, if an assignment is due on February 28 and the student turned it in on March 2 and the teacher graded and returned the assignment to the student, the field `courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.late` will not be available. I would have expected the field to be available and equal to `true`.

Any advice?

Comment: Did it also happened to other returned `courseWork`? I'm not sure if that's the expected behavior once the `courseWork` change its SubmissionState to 'TURNED_IN', you can also file an [issue report](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?labels=Type-Defect,API-Classroom) to validate this behavior.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot The behavior is the same for all returned `courseWork`. I can't say if it's the expected behavior but it's an important information and it's not there

Answer (score 0):

It is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36755695) and has been assigned since Apr 5.

I'm also hoping for the behaviour as described by the OP. There's nothing that can be done but wait for the issue to be resolved by Google.